# Python evdev not finding devices

Tags: python, evdev

I'm writing a game using python, and I need to monitor keyboard events using **evdev**. I'm new to this lib, so I followed the tutorial online. The following is the script mentioned in the tutorial:

```
>>> import evdev

>>> devices = [evdev.InputDevice(path) for path in evdev.list_devices()]
>>> for device in devices:
>>>     print(device.path, device.name, device.phys)
```

However, after running the code, the output of list_devices() is None, which indicates that there is no input devices on my computer(a Dell laptop).Why?

Comment: Also, which Linux are you using?

Comment: my linux is  ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What does `ls /dev/input` show?

Comment: The output is: by-id    event1   event12  event2  event5  event8  mouse0
by-path  event10  event13  event3  event6  event9  mouse1
event0   event11  event14  event4  event7  mice    mouse2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked it on my `debian` Buster system, I think it should be the same for you - you need special access to read and write to the devices. For example, `sudo` should work, try:

```
bash>sudo python3
>>>import evdev; evdev.list_devices()
```

Found the relavent [doc](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html):

> If you do not see any devices, ensure that your user is in the correct group (typically input) to have read/write access.

So add your user to the `input` group - probably safer than `sudo`.

Comment: Just reading this https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/bh4ex1/is_adding_a_user_to_input_group_secure/ , and I am wondering if indeed adding a user to input is not such a great idea?

Comment: On the other hand... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057120/is-adding-a-user-to-input-group-secure